# Keep a specific range of items in a list python

Tags: python

I have the following nested list in python (just an example):

```
[{'512', '530', '788'}, {'112', '401', '276', '280', '787', '555'}, {'284', '041', 'V64.0', 'E8798', 'V15.8', '205'}]
```

I desire the following output:

```
[{'512', '530', '788'}, {'112', '401', '276'}, {'284', '041', 'V64.0'}]
```

Explanation: I just want to keep a specific number of items per list.

Comment: Based on which criterion? In your example you seem to imply that it is the 3 first of each "list". But, firstly, you need to say it, rather that let people reverse engineer your example. And secondly, those are not lists but sets. And sets have no order. So, there is no such thing as the "3 firsts", and no guarantee that the 3 that would be kept are the 3 first displayed.

Comment: @Yubo that would work if they were indeed lists. Since they are sets, you should `[list(e1)[:3] for e1 in l]` rather. Or even `[set(list(e1)[:3]) for e1 in l]` to keep a list of sets. Because `e1[:3]` is impossible if e1 is a set (set are not indexable).

Comment: Sets are at least iterable, so you can use `itertools.islice(e1, 3)` instead. That can be passed to `list`, `set`, etc to get the desired final iterable without converting the entire set `e1` to a full list first.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (note: the  items in the list are sets, so unordered. If the order is important chose tuple or list):

```py
out = [{a, b, c} for a, b, c, *_ in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'512', '530', '788'}, {'280', '555', '276'}, {'041', '284', '205'}]
```

Comment: Similarly, you can use `set(islice(x, n)) for n in lst` if the value of `n` is unknown or just too large to make enumerating the elements unfeasible. (It also avoids having to unpack more elements of `lst` than are necessary to construct the final set.)

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [{'512', '530', '788'}, {'112', '401', '276', '280', '787', '555'}, {'284', '041', 'V64.0', 'E8798', 'V15.8', '205'}]

[set(tuple(x)[:3]) for x in lst]

#or

[set(list(x)[:3]) for x in lst]

[{'512', '530', '788'}, {'280', '401', '787'}, {'205', 'V15.8', 'V64.0'}]
```

---

This could also do the job if we are looking for another method. It avoids turning the set into a list or tuple.

```
lst = [{'512', '530', '788'}, {'112', '401', '276', '280', '787', '555'}, {'284', '041', 'V64.0', 'E8798', 'V15.8', '205'}]

[{e for (e, _) in zip(x, range(3))} for x in lst]          # here range specifies the number of elements needed.

[{'512', '530', '788'}, {'280', '401', '787'}, {'205', 'V15.8', 'V64.0'}]
```